# Should I pursue airfoils with higher or lower peaks (I am doing wind power in science olympiad and am designing a mini wind turbine)?

Tags: wind-power, bernoulli, wind

I am a beginner in wind power, but I know the basics.

1. The Bernoulli effect: Air travelling over the curved edge travels more distance over the same amount of time than the straight side.
   Due to this, I am assuming that no matter how long the curved edge, the air will still get there.
   But this does not follow common sense as if the airfoil is too long, the air along the curved edge will travel so slow that the Bernoulli effect would be nominal/nullified.
   I did testing with paper (obviously was terrible idea, was rushed day of, because the paper wasn't crafted properly, leading to a rough airfoil, therefore leading to turbulence), and found airfoils with taller peaks performed better. I would like to know if there is a sweet spot to this, or if I should try to make them as tall as possible (without interfering with the other blades, of course)

Comment: Check out the design of wind turbine blades. why do they taper? What speeds are they designed for? Will you have a varying air speed to deal with or a constant one?